# Consulta solo retorna un valor de varios que deberia retornar

Tags: laravel

nuevamente estoy entrampado en una función que llevo 2 dias haciendo y anda que me salga... Tengo una función en mi controlador que recibe 2 parámetros para poder retornan registros a un json), hasta el momento he conseguido que me retorne la información, pero solo me retorna un registro (puede ser uno o mas de uno que deba retornarme).

Para entender el contexto: Debo obtener todos los materiales (Tabla Materials) que estén almacenados en "Bodega Nuevos" (Tabla Bodegas) y que sean de un servicio especifico (Tabla Servicios)

Tengo las relaciones en los modelos y como les comento me trae dato, pero solo uno (en este caso me deberia traer 3 mas que son los que tengo actualmente)

EDIT: Con esta funcion que dejo abajo, me estaria trayendo la informacion, pero tengo el problema que si quiero hacer un select de los campos que necesito, solo trae una fila, las demas no...

```
public function getMaterialBodegaServicio($bodega_id,$servicio_id){
        /* $materiales_ids = DB::table('materials')->where('servicio_id',$servicio_id)->pluck('id');
        $materiales = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials')->where('bodega_id',$bodega_id)->whereIn('material_id',$materiales_ids)->pluck('material_id');
        $materiales_finales = DB::table('materials')->whereIn('id',$materiales)->get(); */
        $bodegas = Bodega::select('id','nombre_bodega','tipo_bodega')->where('id',$bodega_id)->get();
        $servicios = Servicio::select('id','servicio')->where('id',$servicio_id)->get();
        $materiales_ids = DB::table('materials')->where('servicio_id',$servicio_id)->pluck('id');
        $materiales = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials')->where('bodega_id',$bodega_id)->whereIn('material_id',$materiales_ids)->pluck('material_id');
        $materiales_finales = DB::table('materials')->whereIn('id',$materiales);

        $data = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials')
        ->Join('ingreso_materials','ingreso_materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.ingreso_material_id')
        ->Join('materials','materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.material_id')
        ->Join('bodegas','bodegas.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.bodega_id')
        ->Join('servicios','servicios.id','=','ingreso_materials.servicio_id')
        ->Join('tecnicos','servicios.id','=','tecnicos.servicio_id')
        //->where('materials.id','det_ingreso_materials.material_id')
        ->where('servicios.id',$servicio_id)
        ->where('bodegas.id',$bodega_id)
        ->where('bodegas.tipo_bodega','Bodega Nuevos')->get();
    /*     //->groupBy(['bodegas.nombre_bodega'])
        ->distinct()
        ->pluck('bodegas.id');
        $bodegas=DB::table('bodegas')->whereIn('tipo_bodega',function ($query) {
            $query->select('tipo_bodega')->from('bodegas')->Where('tipo_bodega','=','Bodega Nuevos');
        }); */

        //dd($data);
        return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200);
    }
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Y probaste hacer el agrupamiento mediante el enlace que te compartí en la otra pregunta?

Comment: si, y tampoco me resulto

Comment: ¿Y por qué no puebas indicando de forma explícita en el `SELECT` que columnas deseas recuperar y de ese mismo modo pasas esas columnas al `group by`?

Comment: @BetaM mi error estaba en que estaba indicando mas de un select y al parecer en un solo  ->select(...) iban los campos que queria traer